# Oozie and Hue: why am I getting "permission denied" error while playing oozie workflow?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I'm new to Hue and Oozie. I installed a Cloudera 5 cluster, with Hue.
I logged in on Hue as Thomas, and created an Oozie dashboard that runs just a hive script.
But, when I launch the dashboard, I get the following error claiming that is not possible to write on inode /tmp/hadoop-yarn:

```
2015-06-12 13:36:01,014  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[cdh-master] USER[thomas] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000000-150612132534763-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-150612132534763-oozie-oozi-W@hive2-3283] Error starting action [hive2-3283]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: Permission denied: user=thomas, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp/hadoop-yarn":yarn:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:216)
```

I made some search on stackoverflow and so, and already add the following lines:

- on HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-conf/core-site.xml:

  `<property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.thomas.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.thomas.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
  </property>`
- On OOZIE_HOME/oozie-site.xml:

  `<property>
      <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.thomas.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.thomas.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
  </property>`

It does not seem to have any effects.
Does anyone has an idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find a solution, but I don't feel satisfied: I changed the rights of the directory "/tmp/hadoop-yarn" to 777. This way, everyone can write into it.
This can be done this way:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop -fs chmod 777 /tmp/hadoop-yarn
```

Does anyone has a better idea?